# Remove Column values having Single word only from a Data Frame using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I am new to programming. I have a DataFrame shown in as below:

```
Col-2               Col-3
have a account      A
account summary     B
Cancel              C
Both                D
Update credit card  E
Block Credit card   F
```

I need my output as:

```
Col-2               Col-3
have a account      A
account summary     B
Update credit card  E
Block Credit card   F
```

Means I need those values where `Col-2` is having more than one word. Single word present in `Col-2` should be removed. `Both` and `Cancel` are single words, that's why those rows have been removed from the output.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension here can be faster than `pandas` `str` methods. Use it to get the length of each value in `Col-2` after you split it, and index your dataframe by whether that length is greater than 1:

```
>>> df[[len(i.split())>1 for i in df['Col-2'].values]]

                Col-2 Col-3
0      have a account     A
1     account summary     B
4  Update credit card     E
5   Block Credit card     F
```

Comment: I am getting an error " AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split'" while executing the above query. What should i do??

Comment: Not sure, without seeing the data, but my best guess is to try: `df[[len(i.split())>1 for i in df['Col-2'].astype(str).values]]`